# How to import correctly node module in Electron

Tags: electron

I'm trying to integrate the lmdb library (npm) in electron, but I don't understand how to do it. I'm probably doing it wrong, I'm new on Electron, if you can help me please !

I use preload.js, main.js and renderer

preload.js

```js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', {
    node: () => process.versions.node,
    chrome: () => process.versions.chrome,
    electron: () => process.versions.electron,
    lmdb: () => process.lmdb
    // we can also expose variables, not just functions
})
```

config main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        // resizable: false,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'gigatreelogosvv.ico'),
        // autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
    win.webContents.openDevTools()

}
```

renderer.js

```js
const open = versions.lmdb.open;
let blocks = open({
    path: "./db/blocks",
    compression: true,
});
```

ERROR CONSOLE LOG

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: open is not a function
    at renderer.js:8:14
```

Comment: What are you trying to reach with `versions.lmdb.open`?

Comment: I did wrong, I just need lmdb @Arkellys

Comment: You can access what's exposed with `contextBridge` with `window`